# How to use logger with Koin?

Tags: android, koin

Koin version: 2.1.5

Instructions are missing from documentation [here](https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/starting-koin?id=starting-for-android).

This is what I have:

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            // use AndroidLogger as Koin Logger - default Level.INFO
            androidLogger()

            // use the Android context given there
            androidContext(this@MyApp)

            // module list
            modules(emptyList())
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val logger : Logger by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        logger.debug("onCreate")
    }
}
```

And looks like there is no instance of Logger in the dependency graph:

```
04-26 12:02:03.781 4672-4672/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4672
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'org.koin.core.logger.Logger'. Check your definitions!
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'org.koin.core.logger.Logger'. Check your definitions!
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:247)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:216)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:51)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.getLogger(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding: this logger is used for internal Koin logging. I came to the conclusion by looking into source code. This logger can be used outside of Koin itself `getKoin()._logger.info("hello world")` but I doubt it was the library creator's intention.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now, so it's used for debugging the dependency graph creation. Logging is mentioned so prominently here without being clear what it's for https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/starting-koin?id=logging. Guess documentation can be improved then

Comment: More specifically, it’s throwing that error because you have asked for a `Logger` via the `inject()` function, but you haven’t provided any `single`, `factory`, or `scoped` definition for `Logger`. Koin (as of 2.x) will only provide an instance if you explicitly create a definition for it.